# Old index files of repositories

Tags: debian, repository, gpg

I've deleted some keys from /etc/apt/trusted.gpg and trusted.gpg.d. Then i use apt update and get this message:

> An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. The following signatures were invalid: NO_PUBKEY 4C6E74D6C0A35108

It seems like i just going to install old version of app. So my question is: where do apt keep this "previous index files" and where does it get signature 4C6E74D6C0A35108 since it is not in Release file (pgp-signed file with packages hashes).

Comment: Since not every Linux distribution uses apt, I retagged your question; please further update it if I've guessed incorrectly; thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous index files are stored in `/var/lib/apt/lists`. They’re the last index files which `apt` successfully downloaded and verified.

The key is determined by looking at the `Release` signature, which isn’t in the `Release` file itself but in `Release.gpg` alongside it. Some repositories have an `InRelease` file which has the contents of `Release` with an inline signature.

In your case, the missing key is the PackageCloud Atom key; follow [these instructions](https://packagecloud.io/app/AtomEditor/atom/gpg#gpg-apt) to restore it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I do not need to restore the key, actually. I just was surprised that i can install the packages which has no public key installed at the moment.

Comment: `/var/lib/apt/lists` location is more generally described on man page of `apt.conf.5` as `lists` folder in `The Dir::State section`.